# Is there a more efficient way to slice a list out of the center of another list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, slice

I wrote this code to slice a list out of the center of another and it seems to work, but I feel like it may be possible to do this more neatly and efficiently (possibly with list comprehension)?

```
def get_middle(num, val_list):
    idx_val = (int(num/2) , int(num/2 + num%2))
    center_idx = int((len(val_list) - 1)/2)
    idx_one, idx_two = center_idx-idx_val[0], center_idx+idx_val[1] 
    return val_list[idx_one:idx_two]


test_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
test_num = 3
new_list = get_middle(test_num , test_list )
print(new_list)
```

The output of the above code is: `[3, 4, 5]`

Comment: What’s your expected output for `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`? `[3,4,5]` or `[2,3,4]`?

Comment: @donkopotamus The expected output is `[3, 4, 5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
def get_middle(num, sequence):
    m = (len(sequence) - 1)//2 - num//2
    return sequence[m:m+num]


test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
test_num = 3
print(get_middle(test_num, test_list))
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it in one line.

```
test_list[len(test_list)//2-test_num//3:len(test_list)//2+test_num//3+1]
```

Of course some adjustments have to be done depending on the parity of test_num and the parity of the length of the list.